# Which source book does this page (featuring the outline of a terminator anatomy) come from?

Tags: story-identification, the-terminator-series

Which source book does this page  (featuring the outline of a terminator anatomy) come from?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This image is from *[The Art of Terminator Salvation](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/6076418-the-art-of-terminator-salvation)*.

[image]

The accompanying text clearly indicated that these are concept art designs for Marcus, drawn by [Martin Laing](https://editorial.rottentomatoes.com/article/exclusive-the-look-of-terminator-salvation-with-martin-laing/) who served as the Production Designer for Terminator Salvation.